# iPad Mail app: archived emails on iPad stay in Inbox on Exchange server

Tags: mail.app, ipados, exchange

Since yesterday, I have archived multiple emails (Exchange server) in the Mail app on my iPad. However, on the server, and therefore also on my iPhone and on my Mac, they stay in the Inbox.

In general, the connection seems to work since I do receive new emails on all my devices.

The Mail app says at the bottom „Updated Just Now“ and there is no error message.

Possible causes:

- I moved a large number of emails to the trash mailbox yesterday.
- I am connected via 5G and not via Wi-Fi. I saw in the Settings app: „Your iPad will fetch new data in the background only when on power and Wi-Fi“. However, I use push and not fetch. I have also enabled „Allow more data on 5G“ since I usually work only on 5G and don‘t have a Wi-Fi hotspot available.

I find this quite intransparent: Is iPad still copying emails to the trash? Is there another problem?

Is there a way to know about the not-finished processes?

How can I make syncing work again so that emails I archived on my iPad do not stay in my inbox on my Mac and on my iPhone.

Comment: This is an issue with the Mail app.  Try using Outlook. It integrates with Exchange better.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually a good advice. I now installed Outlook, which also helps me to separate work mail from private mail even better. Outlook app for Exchange and Mail app for iCloud: I guess that will work like a charm.

Comment: I actually do this exact thing because I want to keep business and personal stuff totally separate.  Write up and answer and leave me a comment so I can upvote.

Comment: Thank you, Allan!

Comment: Glad you got everything working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now installed Outlook, which also helps me to separate work mail from private mail even better. The Outlook app for Exchange and the Apple Mail app for iCloud: the native app for each server. So far it works very well.